# Angular HttpRequest retrieve part of response

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a request in which I upload a file and get a JSON response. I want to then use a part of the response which is `body.path`. I keep getting an error that the path doesn't exists.

The response returns:

```
{"success": 1, path: "somestring"}
```

I tried `e.body?.path`, but still no luck.

```
let req = new HttpRequest('POST', globalVar.host + "/upload.php", formData, { responseType: "json", reportProgress: true});

this.http.request(req)
  .subscribe(e=>{
    if(e.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress){
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * e.loaded / e.total);
      this.uploadProgress = percentDone;
    }
    if(e.type == HttpEventType.Response){
      this.fileLocation.emit({"path": e.body.path, "next": true})
    }
  })
```

With `e.body?.path` I get this error at build time.`error TS1005: ':' expected.` and `error TS1003: Identifier expected.`

`e.body.path` gives error `error TS2339: Property 'path' does not exist on type '{}`

Comment: I believe you should call text() method on response e to get content.

Comment: Hm, it seems that text() is outdated. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using Angular 5.2.3

Comment: Have you tried calling like this "e.body['path']" ?

Comment: Yea, still the same... The response I get is a json object.

Comment: Are you sure that with the last one you get an error at build time? That way it should skip any type checks...

Comment: It gives an error at build time, but it builds.

Comment: And it gives an error in Visual Studio Code

Comment: One more thing to try - add type specification for response like this "e : HttpEvent<{path:string}>"

Comment: Still doens't seem to be working

Comment: Have you tried printing entire body to console to see whats in it?

Comment: Yea, I get the full object `{success: 1, path: "something"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to type the body or the ersponse type

**Solution #1 (easiest)**

```
this.fileLocation.emit({"path": (e.body as any).path, "next": true})
```

**Solution #2**

```
interface MyResponse
{
 success: number;
 path: string;
}

this.fileLocation.emit({"path": (e.body as MyResponse).path, "next": true})
```

**Solution #3 (cleanest imho)**

Type directly the response

```
this.http.request(req)
  .subscribe((e: HttpEvent<MyResponse> ) //<== type here
=>{
    if(e.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress){
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * e.loaded / e.total);
      this.uploadProgress = percentDone;
    }
    if(e.type == HttpEventType.Response){
      this.fileLocation.emit({"path": e.body.path, "next": true})
    }
  })
```